# Updating/Deleting User Profile with React on Express

Tags: postgresql, reactjs, express, authentication

I'm working on a web app with React on Express with a Postgresql database, and am working on trying to allow users the ability to delete/update their profiles.  I've updated the controller, model, and routes for these changes, but I'm having an issue figuring out where to send the fetch request from the React component.  Anytime I try to run a delete or an update I get the following on my terminal:

```
PUT /api/auth/1 400 3.468 ms - 24
--- undefined /robots.txt
```

I checked other threads on here and wasn't able to find how I can determine what URL I should point to for these functions.  I think once I get that it should work as intended.  Below are my auth routes and the functions I have set up, if anybody could suggest how I'd determine what URL to point this to I'd really appreciate it.

```
// handle profile update/delete
authRouter.route('/dashboard')
    .get(usersController.show)
    .put(usersController.update)
    .delete(usersController.delete)
```

User Update/Delete functions:

```
  handleUpdateSubmit(e, data, id) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('clicked')
    fetch(`/api/auth/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        fireRedirect: true,
        redirectPath: '/dashboard'
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  userDelete(id) {
    fetch(`/api/auth/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        fireRedirect: true,
        redirectPath: '/'
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Please let me know if there's any information that'd be useful for figuring this out and I'll provide it immediately, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to follow up on this, the issue was with how my functions were ordered.  I moved my authrouter.Route code beneath the login/logout/register functions and it's working as expected.